Pivot Chart no longer responding to VBA code to update the chart type of a named data series - Microsoft Excel
Background
I have inherited a large workbook that contains a significant amount of data which is updated on a monthly basis. This data is summarised in a series of 6 pivot charts, all with subtle differences. There is one particular data series which I need to display as an xlLine type in all 6 of the pivot charts. The previous owner of the spreadsheet told me they wrote some very simple VBA to do this as a button press for each individual pivot chart (as there are times only 1 needs to be updated). This also needs some improvement as I am aware using the ActiveSheet class is less than optimal but this isn't a priority for the time and resource available. The code is below:
Sub FormatChart1()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart1").Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlAreaStacked
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection("Data Series to display as a line").ChartType = xlLine
End Sub

Which repeats for each chart 1 to 6 with the same theme but a different overall chart type, i.e they are not all xlAreaStacked. I have added a slicer to just the first pivot table (therefore the first pivot chart too) so those viewing the chart can easily determine what they want to look at.
In normal circumstances, the VBA works, the slicer works and everything is good.
Problem
The issue I am facing is that every now and again the first pivot chart seemingly stops responding to the VBA code and I am not sure what the driver for the issue is. This occurs sometimes after all the data is refreshed using the ALT ARA shortcut, but not all the time and other than this, i don't believe the chart has been edited since it worked previously. The workbook is kept on SharePoint so it is possible someone has tampered with the graph but asking the other individuals with access I have been assured this isn't the case.
This is only the case for the first chart with the slicer, all other 5 charts still work when the first one doesn't. The VBA runs without an error but the chart just doesn't update and change the series to be xlLine.
Things I have tried already
I have used the debug mode in the VB editor to run though line by line (not that there are many lines..!) to check it was selecting the right chart and the right data series. I have confirmed that the only line which doesn't work is the last line,ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection("Data Series to display as a line").ChartType = xlLine
If I manually change the series type by clicking on it in the chart and then using the excel interface to change the combo chart type, it works and changes the series type as expected, which is what really confused me.
I have also compared the pivot chart settings to all of the other pivot charts and they are identical.
Current fix
The only rectification I can find is to delete the pivot chart and insert a new one, rename the new chart to have the same name as the last one and then it works again.
One theory I had was linked to the slicer somehow but I have no idea if that is the case, as when the new pivot chart is inserted the slicer can be used as normal for a while and then randomly stops working again.
I am mainly keen to understand if anyone knows why this might be happening in the first place so I can avoid situations that cause it. Failing that, if anyone knows how to make the VBA function again that would be really helpful too.

Have you looked at the Help link for FullSeriesCollection?  There is a note about "Show hidden data in rows and columns".

Chart.FullSeriesCollection

Thanks for that - I have looked in those settings and I can confirm there are no hidden rows in the data and the empty cells are currently shown as zero.

Here are some potential reasons and solutions for the problem you're experiencing:
Possible Causes:
Slicer Interference: The slicer might be affecting the pivot chart in a way that interferes with how VBA interacts with the chart. This could be due to the chart not being fully refreshed or updated when the slicer changes, leading to the VBA code failing to apply changes to the series.
Corrupted Chart Object: Sometimes, chart objects can become corrupted, especially when a workbook is used by multiple people or is stored in a shared environment like SharePoint. This might explain why deleting and recreating the chart temporarily solves the problem.
Excel Bug or Glitch: Excel sometimes behaves unpredictably, especially with complex workbooks that involve multiple pivot tables, charts, and slicers. There might be an underlying Excel bug that occasionally prevents the VBA code from properly interacting with the chart.
Issue with the Data Series Reference: If the data series reference somehow changes or becomes invalid (even if it's not visible in the interface), the VBA code might not be able to find the series to change its type.
Potential Solutions:
1, Refactor the VBA Code:
Instead of using ActiveSheet and ActiveChart, explicitly reference the worksheet and chart objects. This will reduce the chances of errors due to the wrong chart or worksheet being active.
Check if the chart and the series exist before trying to change the series type.
Example:
Sub FormatChart1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cht As ChartObject
    Dim series As Series

    ' Set the worksheet and chart object explicitly
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Replace with your actual sheet name
    Set cht = ws.ChartObjects("Chart1")
    
    ' Check if the chart and the series exist
    If Not cht Is Nothing Then
        cht.Activate
        cht.Chart.ChartType = xlAreaStacked

        On Error Resume Next ' Handle potential error
        Set series = cht.Chart.FullSeriesCollection("Data Series to display as a line")
        On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling
        
        If Not series Is Nothing Then
            series.ChartType = xlLine
        Else
            MsgBox "Series not found.", vbExclamation
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Chart not found.", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub

2, Force a Refresh Before Applying the Change:
Before changing the series type, force a refresh of the pivot table/chart to ensure it's fully updated.
ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
Application.CalculateFull
3, Test with Manual Refresh:
Before running the VBA code, manually refresh the pivot table and slicer to see if it affects the outcome. This might help determine if the issue is related to the timing of the updates.
4, Consider Moving the Slicer:
As an experiment, try moving the slicer to another worksheet and see if the problem persists. This might help confirm if the slicer is part of the issue.
5, Log Chart State:
Add logging to your VBA code to capture the state of the chart and series before and after the code runs. This might give you clues if something unexpected is happening to the chart object or series.
Long-Term Solution:
If the issue continues to be a problem, consider automating the chart recreation process in VBA as a fallback. This would involve a script that deletes the existing chart and creates a new one from scratch, applying all necessary formatting and settings.
Rather lengthy but i hope some of this helps. Best of luck to you.

Thank you very much for all your pointers, I really appreciate the effort made here! I have tried all of the points and unfortunatly no success, still facing the same issue. Your example code was helpful though and works for the other 5 charts
